# Word document to mathml?

Tags: ms-word, mathml

I have lots of word documents which contain math equations, some tables, and some expressions written in superscript and subscript.  Is there a good tool besides MathType for converting my equations to mathml?

Answer (score 2):

If the expressions are entered as mathzones in Word 2007 or later's in-build math formatter then Word includes a transformation to MathML built in, you can select (by an option in the ribbon) that if you cut and paste any math expression then they MathML version will be placed on the clipboard. If you want to bulk convert all the expressions in a document rather than manual cut and paste there is an old blog of mine on the subject at

http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/xhtml-and-mathml-from-office-20007.html

Comment: but what when expressions created  using both mathzones and external objects ?

Comment: in that case you need two or potentially three or four different conversions. word2007 mathzones, word equation editor objects, mathytype objects, and plain text with font changes and superscripts are all internally completely different structures in the word file. Word has in-built conversion for the first, MathType should be able to convert the second two, for plain text superscripts (which really are an input error and should never have been used for mathematics) you need to extract them somehow and convert them to something useable.

Comment: Thanks david,for that reason now we are  converting or rewriting all expressions in to mathtype so that only one click can convert whole document for now.